# How to get size of character with custom font size

Tags: swift, xcode, size, character, pixel

How can I get a size of character with custom font size? I need to know how many pixels takes a dot or another character with different font size.

I'm trying to find out how many dots can contains in my label, before label will break the line.

```
class DotsLabel: UILabel
{
override func layoutSubviews()
{
    super.layoutSubviews()

    if self.text == nil { self.text = "." }
    while Int(self.bounds.width) - Int(self.intrinsicContentSize.width) > 6
    {
        self.text = self.text! + "."
    }
}
}
```

Comment: This is a very broad question. Do you have any specific attempts at a piece of code that tries to figure it out yourself? If you do, please post it so we can help look it over; otherwise we have no context about what you're doing or working with.

Comment: @bj7, added some info

Answer (score 2):

let label = UILabel()

label.text = "Your character"

label.font = label.font.withSize(your size)

let charWidth = label.intrinsicContentSize.width